# Cluster analysis on more than 2 variables

Tags: machine-learning, clustering, k-means, hierarchical-clustering

I was wondering how is cluster analysis is done when more than 2 variables are considered. For example, I was told to do a clustering with the following combinations:

1. Longitude and latitude
2. Longitude, latitude and mean
3. Longitude, latitude, mean and elevation

As far as I know, I am aware that you could visualize the data points of the two variables on the x and y each, but how would one do a cluster analysis with more than two variables? Thanks in advance.

Comment: This question is too broad to be answered here - you really need a book.  But cluster analysis is often done on many more than 2 variables.

Answer (score 1):

Almost the entire literature on clustering is *multivariate*.

If you look only at a single variable, I"d rather use kernel density estimation (KDE), PDFs, CDFs etc. to model the data rather than clustering.